# Is calling a function invertible without knowing its domain and codomain too bold an assumption?

Tags: functions, definition

Would I be right in saying you couldn't determine whether a function is surjective without any knowledge of its domain and codomain?

I mean say we had a function $f(x)=2x+3$.

Sure it's invertible right now so we could say the inverse is $f^{-1}(x)=\frac{x-3}{2}$

And then one may assume that because we have shown that this is invertible that we can now claim bijectivity and therefore subjectivity.

But I feel like this is a told bold a leap having no knowledge of the domain and codomain.

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow [3,5,7]$ then 7 is an element of the codomain that has no element to map to it from the domain.

Do you see what I mean ?

Comment: Yes indeed.  It is however clear in many contexts that we intend for a function to be a "*real function*" implying that its domain and codomain are both the entirety of the real numbers $\Bbb R$, or at least is the maximal subset of the real numbers for which the function can be defined.  Officially, however, one should whenever possible explicitly state the domain and codomain intended to be used as part of the function definition.

Comment: When you write $[0,1]$, do you mean the interval containing $0$, $1$, and all real numbers between $0$ and $1$ (what the notation $[0,1]$ usually means when talking about functions of real numbers), or do you mean just the set containing $0$, $1$, and nothing else? I ask because you also wrote $[3,5,7]$, which doesn't seem to be notation for an interval.

Comment: You are correct. But don't use square brackets for sets. $[0,1]$ means the real numbers between $0$ and $1,$ inclusive, while $[3,5,7]$ is meaningless. Write $\{0,1\}$ and $\{1,3,5\}$ for sets. In MathJax you have to put a backslash `$\{0,1\}$`

Comment: A less artificial example would be with $f$ having domain and codomain $\mathbb Z.$

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed somewhat hasty to declare this function bijective, but there are certain mathematical traditions that would help save your skin here. Particularly, $x, y, z$ variables are often used to indicate a real number, while $n, m$ may indicate an integer, $p, q$ being primes or factors, $a, b, c$ being particular indices of a small or arbitrary set, and so on. This shorthand is used very often to "pre-notate" the domain sets. Strictly speaking, the definition of a function is incomplete without a defined mapping. In your example, $f(x) = 2x+3$ really does not specify which domain and codomain it uses. It would be necessary to write in full $$f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$$ to indicate that $f$ is a function in the set of all functions mapping reals to reals, as opposed to the possible $$f : \{0,1\} \to \{3,5,6\}$$ function.

Here's the real, proper answer to what you mean, though: if you see a function defined around terms looking like $f$ or $x$ *and* you later found from your professor or proctor that you made a mistake because they "never showed the behavior of the function outside of [xyz abc] domain and codomain..." that you can write it off as an errata of the assignment for being in-concise and not a failure of your understanding.